# How to display and edit individual records on a form in Access?

Tags: forms

I have built a table in Access that is populated by the end user with a form. Next, **I would like the end user to retrieve a record and be able to edit the fields in form view.**

I see stackoverflow user Hoops asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12551133/991816), excerpt:

> "What I want to do is have the user select a record from the combo
>   box, which then populates the textboxes (I've already managed to do
>   this)."

His "already managed to do this" is what I need to know.

I tried using a combo box, but it did not populate the text boxes, and when I selected multiple columns to be displayed, the fields could not be edited.

I tried using a parameter query to retrieve a search record, but I could not get results to display in the form.

While I know I am supposed to ask specific answerable questions, what I really need to know is the method or strategy I should be using to retrieve a record and be able to edit the fields in form view. If I know the best method, I can usually figure out the tactical.

Thanks for any ideas. 
Melissa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a split view form in Access. More info can be found here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-split-form-HA010075994.aspx